# raise PoetryException(f"Failed to install {path.as_posix()}") for scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, alpine-linux, python-3.9, python-poetry

I want to use alpine image for python for my production, since it is free from security vulnerabilities.

I have a simple project 'my_project' It contains a simple helloWorld program, which is

```
  # helloworld.py
  from sklearn import __version__ as sklearn_version

  def main():
    print(f"Hello, World! Using Scikit-learn {sklearn_version}.")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My pyproject.toml is

```
    [tool.poetry]
    name = "my_project"
    version = "0.1.0"
    description = "A small Python project with Scikit-learn"
    authors = ["Your Name <your@email.com>"]

    [tool.poetry.dependencies]
    python = ">=3.9,<3.10"
    scikit-learn = "^1.3.0"

    [build-system]
    requires = ["poetry>=1.1.0"]
    build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"

    [tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
    pytest = "^6.0"
```

and my Dockerfile is :

```
  FROM python:3.9-alpine

  WORKDIR /app
  RUN apk add --no-cache curl gcc musl-dev
  RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_VERSION=1.3.2 python -

  ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:${PATH}"


  COPY . .

  RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-root --no-dev

  CMD ["python", "helloworld.py"]
```

I get below error

```
The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


PoetryException

Failed to install
```

`/root/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/ab/bb/06/9a4febd4bdf663c71169b02b45c3bf72c69a043d8961fb0c668e8dad14/scikit-learn-1.3.0.tar.gz`

Same thing works fine for python 3.9.17 slim buster image. How to fix it for alpine ?

Comment: alpine doesn't do WHLs so this needs to be built - try installing python3-dev

Comment: I solved this by using , python3-dev and poetry 1.5.1

Comment: For some reason, I wanted to downgrade to 1.3.2. The problem still persists